# Google Cloud Authorized HTTP requests in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make an authorized request to a Google Cloud function from within Python using this code:

```
import google.auth  
from google.auth.transport.urllib3 import AuthorizedHttp 

credentials, project = google.auth.default()
authed_http = AuthorizedHttp(credentials)
url = "MY_CLOUD_FUNCTON_URL"
response = authed_http.request('POST', url)
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_scope: Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided.', '{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided."}')
```

which makes me think my credentials aren't setup properly but the call works if I run it from the command line using:

```
gcloud functions call MY_CLOUD_FUNCTION --data '{"name":"example"}'
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Where are you running the Python script which is invoking the function?

Answer (score 1):

The answer here depends on where you're trying to call the function from.

If it's inside GCP infrastructure (App Engine, Cloud Functions, etc) you should use the steps in the ["Function-to-functon"](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#function-to-function) section of ["Authenticating Developers, Functions, and End-users"](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating).

If it's external, you should follow the ["Service-to-function"](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#service-to-function) guide instead.