# Calling a Google Cloud Function from within Python using googleapiclient

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to call a Google Cloud Function from within Python in a production environment. I have started with this code:

```
  import googleapiclient.discovery
  from google.oauth2 import service_account

  SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = $PATH_TO_SECRETS

  credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
          SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE)

  compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
```

but from here I am not sure how to call my google cloud function.  Does anyone know the best way for me to do it?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61574031/google-cloud-authorized-http-requests-in-python/61597544?

Comment: The answer depends on what you are trying to do. Are you trying to call Cloud Function management APIS or are you trying to call a Cloud Function HTTP Endpoint?

Comment: If you are trying to call the management API refer to this documentation http://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/cloudfunctions_v1.html If you are trying to call HTTP endpoints refer to this documentation https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating

Comment: To understand the REST API https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest